# Adding polygons to Leaflet inset map in R

Tags: r, leaflet

I've created a map using the Leaflet package in R and added an inset locator map using `addMiniMap()`. I would like to add polygons features to said inset map.

I've already added the polygons to the main map. Currently, my code looks something like this (simplified), where `myPolys` is a `SpatialDataFrame` object.

```r
map <- leaflet(myPolys) %>% addPolygons(params...) %>% addMiniMap(params...)
```

Looking at the documentation for the R package [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leaflet/leaflet.pdf) I'm not 100% sure that this is even possible. Am I right?

Comment: After doing a bit more research it seems to me that this would best be accomplished using Javascript code via htmlwidgets::onRender, similar to this example https://rpubs.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet-minimap.